# How do I build a UI for input/output mapping?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Reading a csv files header or something similar I would like to create an OrderedDictionary with mapped colnames for output.

Something like:

```
{ 
'email' -> 'email address'.
'postal code' -> 'zip code'
}
```

What widget could I use as a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An FTTableMorph? Take a look at FTExamples

Comment: I use Pharo 4 where do I find the FT Package?

Comment: thx, found it here: http://smallworks.eu/web/blog/2015-07-02-fast-table-for-pharo